# Webview not displaying full text

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code

```
var body = "<style type=\"text/css\">body { font-size: 18px; line-height: 28px; } h1 { font-size: 34px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 12px; line-height: 1.3;  } h2 { font-size: 26px; font-weight: 700; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: left; line-height: 34.5px; letter-spacing: -0.45px; } p, i, a { margin-top: 21px; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: -0.03px; line-height: 1.57; }</style>";
body += intent.getStringExtra("body")

webview.loadData(body, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

The webview is not displaying all of the content in "body". Can anyone please help? Please see my activity

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Have you enabled JavaScript? Check it!

Comment: how do we do that? @PrajwalW